# SQL PIVOT on Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, pivot

I am attempting to pivot this list of dates to be used as column headers. The sample query has been simplified for 12 calendar months **Note:** the actual date range will end up being 240 months total. I am not quite grasping the PIVOT function

```
DROP TABLE if exists #nbrs
DROP TABLE if exists #nbr

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20210101'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '20211201'

SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, nbr - 1, @StartDate) AS DateRange
    FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
          FROM      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs 
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

| DateRange |
| --- |
| 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-03-01 |
| 2021-04-01 |
| 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-06-01 |
| 2021-07-01 |
| 2021-08-01 |
| 2021-09-01 |
| 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-11-01 |
| 2021-12-01 |

DESIRED OUTPUT:

| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

Comment: only dynamic sql

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite, relatively new here. Appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by using dynamic sql query and pivot function. Besides the date column, I have added another dummy column for the pivot fucnction.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20210101';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '20211201';
DECLARE @DynamicQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ColumnList AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- populate column list 
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDate
)
SELECT @ColumnList = ISNULL(@ColumnList + ',', '')
        + QUOTENAME(DateData)
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 300);

-- Construct dynamic query
SELECT @DynamicQuery = N' WITH DateRange(DateData, AnotherColumn) AS 
      (
          SELECT CAST(''' + CAST(@StartDate AS NVARCHAR) + ''' as Date) as DateData, 1 as AnotherColumn
          UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,DateData), 1 as AnotherColumn
          FROM DateRange 
          WHERE DateData <  ''' + CAST(@EndDate  AS NVARCHAR) + '''
      )
      SELECT ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM (
      SELECT * FROM DateRange
    ) As SouceTable PIVOT (MAX(AnotherColumn) FOR DateData IN ( ' +
    @ColumnList + ')) AS PivotTable
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 300)';

-- run @DynamicQuery;
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery;
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Yared. However when I expand the start and end to a 10 year span, i receive a recursion error:  Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.   the goal for my particular use is to enable a dynamic date range of 240 months (10 years)

Comment: That happens because of the CTE's (Common Table Expressions) recursion level  surpasses the default limit, (i.e., 100). The issue can easily be fixed by increasing threshold using MAXRECURSION option. I have upated the query to accomodate this change.